# WP 7 - LINQ select statement from List<> error C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, windows-phone-7, select

I have problem with Linq statement. I want select some "MySong" from the List:

```
var filteredList = from s in list
                   where s.Title.Contains("test")
                   select s;
```

but I get this error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Has someone solve this problem? Do you have tips how to select only songs, which contains for example "test"? thx for reply.

Comment: What type is "list" in your LinQ query?

Comment: According to exception, the problem is in another place of your code which you didn't provide.

Comment: I suppose you include `using System.Linq`? What type is a `list`?

Comment: Post the code that shows how you're populating the list.

Comment: Please list the `using` statements that you've included in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the top of the code file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And make sure the project has System.Core in the references.

Comment: Had to try; what is the `list` type?

Comment: ObservableCollection<MySong> but if I try List<MySong> or var List I get the same error...

Comment: What about the project references, do you have System.Core in them?